# Finding the curve from the given equation.

Tags: geometry

The equation given is as follows :
$X^{4}-Y^{4}+2Y^{3}+2XY(Y-X)=0$.
We are asked to find out the type of curve represented by the above equation.I dont remember the options well.But it was like

$1$.equation of $2$ circles

$2$.equation of $2$ lines

$3$.equation of a circle and line

Can someone help me to solve this ?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote that down properly? For whatever it's worth, I just graphed that curve in Mathematica, and it doesn't appear to be any of those things.

Comment: What are you getting?I am not very sure about the options.Forget the options.Please tell me what you are getting.

Comment: I'm getting two weird almost-lines that become curvy shapes near the origin. The reason I asked if you wrote it down correctly is that if you had an extra factor of $-2X^3$ in there, you'd get $X^4 - Y^4 + 2(Y^3 - X^3) + 2 X Y (Y - X)  = (X - Y) (X + Y) (-2 X + X^2 - 2 Y + Y^2) = 0$, which is exactly the equation for two lines and one circle.

Comment: Anyway thanx for the reply.I am happy with your reply.Maybe the question was wrong.

Comment: Can yu write the full steps on how you coverted that equation into this form of 2 lines and a circle?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can see what the original curve looks like in WolframAlpha (though it has some resolution problems): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E4%20-%20y%5E4%20%2B%202y%5E3%20%2B%202xy(y%20-%20x)%20%3D%200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indeed missing a factor of $2X^3$.
As for factoring here it is-
$$X^4-Y^4+2Y^3-2X^3+2XY(Y-X)=0$$
$$=(X^2+Y^2)(X^2-Y^2)+2(Y-X)(X^2+Y^2+XY)+2XY(Y-X)$$
$$=(X-Y)(X+Y)(X^2+Y^2)+2(Y-X)(X^2+Y^2+XY)+2XY(Y-X)$$
Factoring out $(Y-X)$
$$=(Y-X) \ [ \ (X+Y)(-X^2-Y^2)+2(X^2+Y^2+XY)+2XY \ ]$$
$$=(Y-X) \ [ \ (X+Y)(-X^2-Y^2)+2(X^2+Y^2+XY+XY) \ ]$$
$$=(Y-X) \ [ \ (X+Y)(-X^2-Y^2)+2(X^2+Y^2+2XY) \ ]$$
$$=(Y-X) \ [ \ (X+Y)(-X^2-Y^2)+2(X+Y)(X+Y) \ ]$$
Factoring out $(Y+X)$
$$=(Y-X)(Y+X)(-X^2-Y^2+X+Y)$$
Now either $x+y=0$ => $x=-y$ 
or $x-y=0$ => $x=y$ (equations of line)
or $(-X^2-Y^2+X+Y)=0$ (equation of circle)